# how can I fix password validation conditions with correct regex?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to fix my logical conditions that aren't working as intended.

For instance, the "2 digits in a password" condition fails on `1test2` even though it has 2 digits in it.

My rules are:

- password must have at least 2 digits
- password must have at least 6 letters
- password must have at least 1 special character
- password must be at least 8 characters long

https://codepen.io/skybulk/pen/OJNMPYO

```
function checkPassword(pwd){
  const special_characters = "[~\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+{}\":;,'\[\]]"
  if(/[0-9]{2,}/.test(pwd)){ // at least 2 digits
    return true;
  }
  if(/[a-zA-Z]{6,}/.test(pwd)){ // at least  6 letters
    return true;
  }
  if(new RegExp(special_characters).test(pwd)){ // at leas 1 special character
    return true;
  }
  if(pwd.length < 8){
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: That code's logic is wrong. You should not be returning true and exiting on the check. SHould be in NOT true, return false

Comment: how can I do it properly?

Comment: You want to check for the logical inverse of these cases (e.g. `if (!/[0-9]{2,}/.test(pwd))`, and then return false in any of those cases. Then at the end return true (not in a conditional) - this will only happen if all other cases have passed and therefore the password meets all of the conditions.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones sure, but how can I force my code not follow the order?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones my current code follows the order first digits, then letters, so on, but I want the same without care about the order of the password, but containing the rules only.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I mean without order matters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219702/discussion-between-woundedstevenjones-and-raul-delgado-de-luna).

Comment: The last rule is slightly redundant with the other 3 rules. If the first 3 rules match a password, then by definition it will be a minimum of 9 characters long already.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
const regex = /^(?=.{8})(?=(?:\D*\d){2})(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){6})(?=[^~!@#$%^&*()_+{}":;,'[\]]*[~!@#$%^&*()_+{}":;,'[\]])/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wS46Ei/1) (the pattern is a bit modified to avoid matching line breaks as the demo is performed against a single multiline string).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){2})` - password must have at least 2 digits
- `(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){6})` - password must have at least 6 letters
- `(?=[^~!@#$%^&*()_+{}":;,'[\]]*[~!@#$%^&*()_+{}":;,'[\]])` - password must have at least 1 special character
- `(?=.{8})` - password must be at least 8 characters long.

You may write the regex with comments inside the code, too:

```js
const regex = new RegExp("^" + // start of string
  "(?=.{8})" + // must be at least 8 characters long
  String.raw`(?=(?:\D*\d){2})` + // must have at least 2 digits
  "(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){6})" + // must have at least 6 letters
  String.raw`(?=[^~!@#$%^&*()_+{}":;,'[\]]*[~!@#$%^&*()_+{}":;,'[\]])` // must have at least 6 letters
);
console.log(regex);
```

Comment: It might be easier to split the regexp up into parts for easier maintenance.

Comment: `(?=.{8})` is useless, 2 digits + 6 letters + 1 special is 9 char long.

Comment: @Toto No, it will fail the wrong strings quicker since it is the first lookahead after `^`

Answer (score 0):

I have not made any changes to your Regexp - only to the logic surrounding it. You might want to start with a variable `valid` and if any of these conditions are not met you can set `valid = false`. At the end of your function you want to return `valid` which will be a boolean of `true` or `false` depending on whether the password passed all tests.

```
function checkPassword(pwd){
  let valid = true;

  const special_characters = "[~\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+{}\":;,'\[\]]"
  if (!/[0-9]{2,}/.test(pwd)){ // at least 2 digits
    valid = false;
  }
  if (!/[a-zA-Z]{6,}/.test(pwd)){ // at least  6 letters
    valid = false;
  }
  if (!new RegExp(special_characters).test(pwd)){ // at least 1 special character
    valid = false;
  }
  if (!pwd.length < 8){
    valid = false;
  }

  return valid;
}
```

Side note: Complex password validation can be restrictive to the user. It is far more secure to encourage a user to have a longer password (or pass phrase) than a shorter password with a few special characters.

Comment: This gives false for `1abc2def&`, should be true, 2 digits, 6 letters, 1  special, 9 char long.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. It seems easier to read and maintain:

```js
function checkPassword(pwd){
  const special_characters = /[%~!@#$\^&*()_+{}":;,'\[\]]/;
  return   pwd.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').length >= 2
        && pwd.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '').length >= 6
        && special_characters.test(pwd)
        && pwd.length >= 8
}

console.log(checkPassword('FF%lkf%jd%fk12'));
```

The idea is for every condition, remove all not-to-be-tested characters. Then you have the length of the characters that you are testing.

Bear in mind that in javascript, you can create a Regex object with the syntax:

```
some_variable = /foobar/;
```

You can create it via `new Regex`, however, in that case you are passing a string to the constructor. So if the regex was supposed to have a backslash, you should scape it too. Also, as regular strings, quotes should be scaped (one backslash).

This two are equivalent:

```
special_characters = /[%~!@#$\^&*()_+{}":;,'\[\]]/;

special_characters = new Regex("/[%~!@#$\\^&*()_+{}\":;,'\\[\\]]/");
```

Note that only `]`, `^`, `-` must be scaped (`[` is recommended and a must on other programming languages)

Also, when I read `\!` I was not sure if you tried to scape `!` (which is unnecessary) or you tried to add backslash to the special character list (I opted for the first)